# Change table column data to utf8

Tags: php, mysql

I have this column of table that contains data like :

```
Maintenant autoris&eacute; &agrav...Pour tout achat d&rsquo
```

I try to convert it so that text appear normally in french language, but i have failure. Behold how i try:

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sarldbcatw');
            mysqli_select_db($conn,'sarldbcatw')or die('Erreur de selection '.mysqli_error());

        $conn->set_charset("utf8");

            $slq = "SELECT * FROM MTbl_mazel_fiche order by Id_fiche";

            $req = mysqli_query($conn,$slq) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br>'.mysqli_error()); 

             while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req))  {

        $fi_descript_fr_grd=htmlentities($data['fi_descript_fr_grd'], ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8"); 
         $fi_descript_fr_grd = htmlspecialchars_decode($fi_descript_fr_grd);
                 $Id_fiche = $data['Id_fiche'];
                // echo $Id_fiche."<br><br>";
                 $sqlfic = "UPDATE MTbl_mazel_fiche SET fi_descript_fr_grd='$fi_descript_fr_grd'  WHERE  Id_fiche =".$Id_fiche;
                 mysqli_query($conn,$sqlfic) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$sqlfic.'<br>'.mysqli_error());

             }
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: `&agrav` or `&agrave;`? `&rsquo` or `&rsquo;`? Also, these entities are in **database field**? If it is, why do you use `htmlentities`?

Comment: thank you for the notice, any proposal to do it ?

Comment: You have to use `html_entity_decode`. But, as per previous comment, it depends of db data. **Why do you use `htmlentities()`**?

Comment: Many many thanks that work perfecty...

Comment: if only i could vote you up !